# Looking for example(s) of differing rulings by Rav Yochanan vs. R' Yose bar Chanina

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

In discussing whose halachic rulings we follow when tanaaim and/or amorim give different rulings, in [Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Klalei_HaTalmud#Rav_Yochanan_and_Other_Amoraim) it says:

> Rav Yochanan vs. R' Yose bar Chanina is a Machaloket (regarding whom we follow).

I certainly don't have extensive coverage in terms of the parts of the Talmud I have learned, but I have not seen any instances where those two have differed.  Can somebody give me an example or two?

Answer (score 1):

The [discussion of the יד מלאכי](https://filebin.net/ol4lwffuk4x11udp) (תקע) mentions a number of examples. (If any other upload site is preferable I can try another one)